# VirtualBox graphics problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, virtualbox, lubuntu

On a guest Windows XP SP3 I have installed Visual C# Express 2010 with the XNA Game Studio 4.0. I have created a simple project and started it and XNA thrown the following error:

`No suitable graphics card found. Could not find a Direct3d device that supports the XNA Framework Reach profile.`

So I have enabled the 3D acceleration in the display tab of the preferences but it didn't change the result, XNA was still unable to find a Direct3D device.
Somebody knows if is possible to use the XNA Game Studio 4.0 in VirtualBox?
I've already installed guest addition with DirectX support in Safe Mode, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles over this, as I did.

I changed the Display-settings in Virtualbox (Win7 guest) from the recommended "VBoxSVGA" to the deprecated "VBoxVGA" (now when I start the machinge, I get a warning) - now the game starts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Virtual-box 3D driver is experimental and is not comparable to a native one. 
Reference https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=195857

Answer (score 0):

Wine may actually be a better way to run this, it has a more comprehensive D3D to OpenGL wrapper. I see that version 3.0 has gold status on WineHQ https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8153 - version 4.0 is untested however